# Generating SASL XOAUTH2 client response for Gmail IMAP access using Ruby

Tags: ruby, oauth, gmail, imap, sasl

I'm trying to access my Gmail emails over IMAP using XOAUTH2 in Ruby.

I've successfully generated an access token (and refresh token) by authenticating using OAuth 2.0 with the [`oauth2`](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) gem. I'm going to use [`gmail_xoauth`](https://github.com/nfo/gmail_xoauth) to access Gmail over IMAP. So I now need to generate the SASL initial client response, as per [the Gmail XOAuth2 docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol):

```
The SASL XOAUTH2 initial client response has the following format:  

    base64("user=" {User} "^Aauth=Bearer " {Access Token} "^A^A")

using the base64 encoding mechanism defined in RFC 4648.
^A represents a Control+A (\001).
```

I'm not clear how I represent the "Control+A" in my string. Do I simply use `^A`?

```rb
key = Base64.encode64("user=#{email}^Aauth=Bearer #{access_token_obj.token}^A^A")
```

[This python script](http://google-mail-oauth2-tools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python/oauth2.py) uses `\1` in place of `^A`. I've also tried `\001`. Whatever I try, when authenticating (in irb) with the result I get:

```rb
>> imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, usessl=true, certs=nil, verify=false)
>> imap.authenticate('XOAUTH2', email, key)
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_write:: bad write retry
```

That error could be entirely unrelated, but I'm not confident any option I've tried is correct.

Comment: That looks entirely like you weren't able to connect to the server.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Although today I'm instead getting this error: `Net::IMAP::NoResponseError:  Invalid credentials (Failure)`. I guess that's progress...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured it out... I didn't need to do the Base64 encoding step at all!

`gmail_xoauth` [adds the `XOAUTH` authenticator](https://github.com/nfo/gmail_xoauth/blob/master/lib/gmail_xoauth/imap_xoauth2_authenticator.rb) to [`Net::IMAP`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html#method-i-authenticate) itself. I realised that this only expects the unencoded `access_token` from Google, rather than the longer Base64-encoded string.

So, if:

```
email = `fredbloggstest@gmail.com`
# The result of the OAuth2 dance (as well as a refresh_token):
access_token = 'ya13.AHES6Y3F54_5fAoz_8VuG-7pzQAo3R0_ukt7dhfgRnJh41Q'
```

then I don't have to Base64 encode anything. I just do:

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, usessl=true, certs=nil, verify=false)
imap.authenticate('XOAUTH2', email, access_token)
```

and I get back:

```
#<struct Net::IMAP::TaggedResponse tag="RUBY0001", name="OK", data=#<struct Net::IMAP::ResponseText code=nil, text="fredbloggstest@gmail.com Fred Bloggs authenticated (Success)">, raw_data="RUBY0001 OK fredbloggstest@gmail.com Fred Bloggs authenticated (Success)\r\n">
```

(As a bonus, [this is a handy Ruby script](https://gist.github.com/jotto/2932998) for getting the `access_token` from the OAuth dance.)

Comment: And maybe if I hadn't got distracted by Google's own docs, I would have seen that `gmail_xoauth`'s README describes how to do this. Idiot.

Comment: Does this still work? I'm getting errors here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443926/oauth2-token-not-working-for-gmail-xoauth-gem