# Can't authorize to Gmail via XOauth2 using Gmail Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail-api

I am attempting to use XOauth2 nd the ruby Gmail gem to read email from Google accounts. While I can retrieve a valid token via Oauth, I get an error trying to connect with the token via the Gmail Gem.

I am using OmniAuth to retrieve and store a token, TOKEN. I have confirmed that it is not expired and can be used to connect via Google::APIClient.

When I attempt to connect as follows:

```
gmail = Gmail.connect(:xoauth2, 'email@gmail.com', :token => TOKEN)
c.login
```

from the console, I see:

```
#<Gmail::Client0x7fb037e80988 (email@gmail.com) disconnected>
```

If I try:

```
c.login!
```

I get the error:

```
Gmail::Client::AuthorizationError: Couldn't login to given Gmail account: email@gmail.com (Invalid credentials (Failure))
```

Reviewing the Gmail gem source code, it looks like this should work. I am unclear how to debug or what I'm missing.

Comment: Try writing 'me' instead of 'email@gmail.com'. Does that work?

Comment: No, that does not work.

Comment: Aah, shoot. Then I don't know. Hopefully someone can chime in.

Comment: How are you sending the access token? Are you sending it as Base64-encoded string. check this link . I think for gmail_Xoauth2, you can send unencoded access token. check this link for sample code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945880/generating-sasl-xoauth2-client-response-for-gmail-imap-access-using-ruby?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

This was a syntax error. The correct syntax is:

```
gmail = Gmail.connect(:xoauth2, 'email@gmail.com', TOKEN)
```